# How to generate url in global.asax using my route. int asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing, global-asax

I have functionality in BeginRequest event in global.asax which parse request url, check some parts of this and redirect user to another url.

Problem: how to generate url from routeName. I want to do this, because if route will be changed, redirect functionality will be working. 
I don't like code:

```
String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", host, part1, part2);
```

In view I can use Url.RouteUrl, but in global.asax i have to create UrlHelper object manually with RequestContext and RouteData parameters. Where can i get the routedata object?

Answer (score 0):

> I have functionality in BeginRequest event in global.asax which parse request url, check some parts of this and redirect user to another url.

A more *MVCish* way to achieve this would be to use a [custom action filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.aspx) and perform this processing in the [OnActionExecuting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.onactionexecuting.aspx) method which will be called before the controller action is invoked:

```
public class CustomFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // read some value from the request
        string value = filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["someValue"] as string;
        if (!IsValueValid(value))
        {
            // if the value is invalid redirect to some controller action
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary(new
                {
                    action = "foo",
                    controller = "bar"
                })
            );
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

And now all that's left is to decorate your base controller with this attribute so that it applies to all actions.

Comment: Thanks for response. But for my case i have to process this situation in global.asax, because i am using unity for injection. If i choose actionfilter attribute mechanism which create controller instance will be executed and if i use begin request no actions will be perfomed. It more high-performance variant

Comment: Any particular reason you have to process this in global.asax? Why not benefit from what ASP.NET MVC has to offer? I mean you've already made the choice of using ASP.NET MVC so then why not doing it properly?

Comment: I didn't finish my answer and press enter :) Sorry. I am new to stack overflow.

Comment: OK, so next question: why instantiating a controller is an expensive operation for you? This shouldn't be the case.

Comment: Creating controller it's not so expensive operation, but in every controller i have inject about 10-15 objects. Some of them as light as thistledown, but some of them more heavy.

Comment: Aren't those objects singleton?

Comment: These objects are not singltons due to my architecture. I want to know how can i get information about selected router, not only because of this functional. It's interesting for me personally. As far as i know in beginrequest event asp.net mvc has choosen route already. Isn't it?

Comment: The `BeginRequest` happens very early in the execution pipeline. The route is selected after.